# How to make OpenGL pick the nearest larger mipmap?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw text with OpenGL using FreeType and to make it sharper, i generate the font texture from FreeType for each mipmap iteration. Everything works quite fine except for one thing. When i do this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

OpenGL chooses the nearest mipmap according to the size of the text, but if available sizes are 16 and 32, and i want 22, it picks 16, making it look terrible. Is there a way to set it so that it instead always picks the nearest larger mipmap?

I know i can do this while rendering the text to set the mipmap level manually:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD, (int) log2(1/scale));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD, (int) log2(1/scale));
```

But is that effective? Doesn't that kind of drop the need for using mipmaps completely? I could just make different textures and choose one according to size. So is there a better way to acomplish this?

Comment: "I want to draw text with OpenGL using FreeType and to make it sharper, i generate the font texture from FreeType for each mipmap iteration." This is not a good idea. The way that FreeType renders smaller text is *not* a way that works well for mipmap interpolation. That's why your GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR text looked terrible; FreeType's small text hinting made the smaller text look wrong. It would be better to just have a certain set of text resolutions that you work with and just use them.

Comment: "That's why your GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR text looked terrible." Rasterized text that is magnified looks worse than similar but larger rasterizations that are minified. I believe that's the biggest reason why OP's approach looks bad.

Comment: Good discussion of mipmap related blur: https://bgolus.medium.com/sharper-mipmapping-using-shader-based-supersampling-ed7aadb47bec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` as the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` parameter?  It should blend between the two nearest mipmaps.  That might improve the appearance.

Also, you could try using the `texture_lod_bias` extension which is documented here:
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_lod_bias.txt

Comment: Yes, i started out with GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, but it was even worse (there were "ghosts" as the different sizes of the letters didn't align that well).

Comment: When I wrote an OpenGL bitmap font utility, I just stuck to a fixed size of output, e.g. 16x24.  Because I was drawing the text in a consistently scaled orthographic projection (basically width/height equal to viewport size) each time, it worked pretty well.  But if you need arbitrary sizes, texture_lod_bias is worth a shot.

Comment: Is `GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS` added before or after `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` does its thing on the technically correct LOD? If it is added before, shouldn't a LOD bias of `-0.5` do what OP wants? It definitely provides better results for me at all sizes, but I am not sure if it does what I think it does.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS` to add a constant to the mipmap level, which could help you accomplish this (for example, by always choosing the next higher mipmap level). However, it could simply be that mipmap-nearest isn't ideal for this situation. If you're always showing your texture in screen-space and know exactly how the font size corresponds to the pixels on the screen, then mipmapping may be too much machinery for you.